# Unable to find what file edits WordPress Custom Posts Page?

Tags: wordpress

I am somewhat new to WordPress. I have experience with it, but not as much as other people.

I have a client who wants a custom post-type to post recipes. Previously, another developer, had worked on the site and created the custom post type "My Recipes"; and it has a page with the url .././samplerecipes.

I can't, for the life of me, find the .php file that edits the template it is using. Any advice would be helpful...I wish I could give you more information but I am really at a loss. I have tested every .php file in the template's folder and tried editing it (and then uploading it via FTP) and nothing seems to have an effect. It is NOT samplerecipes.php (although it seems like it should be)

[image: Template's dir (no, it's not samplerecipes.php... for some reason)]
[image: The admin panel][image: The page that displays the posts]

EDIT: Code that adds the custom post type (in functions.php)

```
// Create Sample Recipe
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type_two' );
function create_post_type_two() {
        $args = array(
        'labels' => post_type_labels( 'My Recipes' ),
        'taxonomies' => array('category'),
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'has_archive' => true,
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'menu_position' => null,
        'supports' => array('title',
            'editor',
            'author',
            'thumbnail',
            'excerpt',
            'custom-fields',
            'comments'
        )
    );

        register_post_type( 'samplerecipes', $args );
}
```

Comment: What is the actual custom post type named, is it actually 'samplerecipes'? Can you post the code that registers the post type?

Comment: Added into the post - I should've added it in before. Sorry about that.

Comment: There seems to be a php file called 'single-samplerecipes.php'. Have you tried that one?

Comment: The screenshot you added should be for the archive of the recipes. Since there is no `archive-samplerecipes.php` or `archive.php`, the template is either defaulting to `index.php` or is using another template in the parent theme.

Comment: AHA! That worked! Thank you :)

Comment: Added as an answer, glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

The screenshot you added should be for the archive of the recipes. Since there is no `archive-samplerecipes.php` or `archive.php`, the template is either defaulting to `index.php` or is using another template in the parent theme

Answer (score 0):

have you tried single-samplerecipes.php ?

have a look at the template hierarchy here :
http://wphierarchy.com/

Comment: I have. It doesn't have effect.

Comment: sorry about that,
should be :
archive-samplerecipes.php, or archive.php or index.php